# Filtering Google Chrome Browsing History

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, history

I'm having trouble filtering my browsing history Google Chrome's history tab.

I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, and click the down arrow next to a site, then select "more from this site".

The result, isn't what what I would have expected.  Instead of filtering the results to a specific site, for example, only showing results from [SuperUser.com](http://www.superuser.com), chrome shows results from other sites as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking `more from this site` just start a search for `superuser.com`. That's quite useless, since all SE sites contain a link to the aforementioned website.

You can fix this by manually changing the `<input>`'s value to `url:superuser.com`. This still isn't perfect (it will also include results from all subdomains, but it's much better.

I don't know why Chrome doesn't do this in the first place. Probably a bug...